# Margin 0 auto will not center two of my divs

Tags: html, css

So, i'm trying to center three of my divs on the page, #header, #nav, and #headerImg.  I can't seem to center my #header and #nav divs using margin: 0 auto; though. They seem to be stuck to the left side of my page when I refresh the page.

Here is my style.css for my page:

```css
div#header{      //I only have one image here.
    position:absolute;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    width: 960px;
    height: 49px;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: #2E5E8D 
}

div#nav{         //I have 4 links here
    position:absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    width: 960px;
    height: 20px;
    top: 69px;
    background-color: #2E5E8D
}

div#headerImg{   //I have one image here, 
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
    top: 95px;
}

div#content{
    position:relative;
    top:109px;
    width:1000px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

div#content a{
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#content a:hover{
    color: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
 
#content dt{
    margin-top: 10px;
}

div#footer{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 109px;
    background-color: #333333;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 1000px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

The width on my `#header` and `#nav` have to be set to **960px** as per instructors request, and I'm sure he wanted the image inside my `#headerImg` to be inside my `#header div`, but i couldn't get the image from overlapping.  Therefore, that's the only div of the 3 that I can center.

I tried using `margin: 0 auto;` and `display: block` on both but they don't seem to work. I tried using `margin: 0 10%` which seemed to work on my computer, but it is misaligned on another computer. My comments in the code are just to show what I have in the div.

Comment: `margin:0 auto;` does not work on absolutely positioned elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add div#header and div#nav the following rules:

```
margin-left: -500px;
left: 50%;
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it, once I did this, I had to change my #headerImg to the same rules as well.  Everything looking good. Thanks again.